# will It evaluate at compile time? (pass const char* as template parametr)

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, boost

**Working example:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/preprocessor/config/limits.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat.hpp>

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// COMPILE-TIME C-STRING PROCESSING:
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#define _DEBUG_MODE_ 1
#define _ERROR_CHK_  1

#define MY_NULLPTR   nullptr

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define __FUNC__ __FUNCTION__
#else
#define __FUNC__ __func__
#endif

///////////////////////////////////
// Configuration:
#define BUFFER_SIZE  100  // Limit: 256 // const char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE]... // you will not find any symbol with name "buffer" it is just an abstraction
#define EMPTY_CHAR   '\0'
#define DEFAULT_MSG  "3W3A]3Aw"

///////////////////////////////////
// Slice char[] into separate char's
constexpr __forceinline
char getCharAt                (const char* cstr, unsigned int i, unsigned int l) {
    return (i < l) ? cstr[i] : EMPTY_CHAR;
}
#define GET_CHAR_AT(z,n,text) , getCharAt(text, n, (sizeof(text) / sizeof(text[0])))
#define SLICE(_cstr)          sizeof(_cstr)/sizeof(_cstr[0]) BOOST_PP_REPEAT(BUFFER_SIZE, GET_CHAR_AT, _cstr)

///////////////////////////////////
// fragments of code to be repeated:
#define ARG(z,n,text)  , const char text ## n // repeat fragment of code n times    // make list of template arguments:
#define LIST(z,n,text) text ## n,             // repeat fragment of code n times:   // make "body" of initializer list

///////////////////////////////////
// Repeat _macro "BUFFER_SIZE" times:
#define REPEAT_MACRO(_macro, _text) BOOST_PP_REPEAT(BUFFER_SIZE, _macro, _text)

///////////////////////////////////
// Cast to std::string:
#define CAST_TO_STRING(_cstr) ((std::string)_cstr)


///////////






///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// ERRCHK:
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#define NAME_OF_ERRCHK_VARIABLE_FILE file
#define NAME_OF_ERRCHK_VARIABLE_FROM from
#define NAME_OF_ERRCHK_VARIABLE_FUNC func
#define NAME_OF_ERRCHK_VARIABLE_MSG  msg
template < unsigned int line,
        // unsigned int length_file, const char file0, const char file1, const char file2, ... , const char fileN // where N = BUFFER_SIZE - 1
           unsigned int length_file REPEAT_MACRO(ARG, NAME_OF_ERRCHK_VARIABLE_FILE),
        // unsigned int length_from, const char from0, const char from1, const char from2, ... , const char fromN // where N = BUFFER_SIZE - 1
           unsigned int length_from REPEAT_MACRO(ARG, NAME_OF_ERRCHK_VARIABLE_FROM),
        // unsigned int length_func, const char func0, const char func1, const char func2, ... , const char funcN // where N = BUFFER_SIZE - 1
           unsigned int length_func REPEAT_MACRO(ARG, NAME_OF_ERRCHK_VARIABLE_FUNC),
        // unsigned int length_msg,  const char msg0,  const char msg1,  const char msg2,  ... , const char msgN  // where N = BUFFER_SIZE - 1
           unsigned int length_msg  REPEAT_MACRO(ARG, NAME_OF_ERRCHK_VARIABLE_MSG ) >
__forceinline
void errchk(bool failure, bool* flag_success = MY_NULLPTR) {
    if (failure) {
     // constexpr const char file[] = { file0, file1, file2, ... , fileN, '\0' }; // where N = BUFFER_SIZE - 1
        constexpr const char file[] = { REPEAT_MACRO(LIST, NAME_OF_ERRCHK_VARIABLE_FILE) EMPTY_CHAR };
     // constexpr const char from[] = { from0, from1, from2, ... , fromN, '\0' }; // where N = BUFFER_SIZE - 1
        constexpr const char from[] = { REPEAT_MACRO(LIST, NAME_OF_ERRCHK_VARIABLE_FROM) EMPTY_CHAR };
     // constexpr const char func[] = { func0, func1, func2, ... , funcN, '\0' }; // where N = BUFFER_SIZE - 1
        constexpr const char func[] = { REPEAT_MACRO(LIST, NAME_OF_ERRCHK_VARIABLE_FUNC) EMPTY_CHAR };
     // constexpr const char  msg[] = { msg0,  msg1,  msg2,  ... , msgN,  '\0' }; // where N = BUFFER_SIZE - 1
        constexpr const char  msg[] = { REPEAT_MACRO(LIST, NAME_OF_ERRCHK_VARIABLE_MSG ) EMPTY_CHAR };
     // print error:
        std::cout << "File: " << NAME_OF_ERRCHK_VARIABLE_FILE         << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Line: " << line                                 << std::endl;
        std::cout << "From: " << NAME_OF_ERRCHK_VARIABLE_FROM << "()" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Func: " << NAME_OF_ERRCHK_VARIABLE_FUNC         << std::endl;
     // print message:
        if(CAST_TO_STRING(msg) != CAST_TO_STRING(DEFAULT_MSG))
            std::cout << "Msg:  " << msg << std::endl;
     // set flag:
        if (flag_success)
            *flag_success = false;
    }
#if (_DEBUG_MODE_)
    else {

    }
#endif
}

///////////






///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// MACROS:
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#if (_ERROR_CHK_)
//> - F stands for Flag.    ERRCHK is using bool flag
//> - C stands for Class.   ERRCHK is using member variables;
//> - M stands for Message  ERRCHK will print user message. mesage must be in format: "my mesage" as c-string and nothing else!!! Otherwise you will see THE GRAND MOTHER OF ALL ERRORS!!!    
#   define ERRCHK(_failure)                                                                   \
        errchk <__LINE__, SLICE(__FILE__), SLICE(__FUNC__), SLICE(#_failure), SLICE(DEFAULT_MSG)> (_failure);

#   define ERRCHK_F(_failure, _flag)                                                          \
        errchk <__LINE__, SLICE(__FILE__), SLICE(__FUNC__), SLICE(#_failure), SLICE(DEFAULT_MSG)> (_failure, &_flag);

#   define ERRCHK_C(_failure, _msg)                                                           \
        errchk <__LINE__, SLICE(__FILE__), SLICE(__FUNC__), SLICE(#_failure), SLICE(DEFAULT_MSG)> (_failure, &(MY_(success)));

#   define ERRCHK_M(_failure, _msg)                                                           \
        errchk <__LINE__, SLICE(__FILE__), SLICE(__FUNC__), SLICE(#_failure), SLICE(_msg)> (_failure);

#else
#   define ERRCHK(_failure)                                                                   \
        _failure;

#   define ERRCHK_F(_failure)                                                                 \
        _failure;

#   define ERRCHK_C(_failure)                                                                 \
        _failure;

#   define ERRCHK_M(_failure)                                                                 \
        _failure;

#endif

///////////






///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// MAIN::
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    bool failure = true;
    ERRCHK(failure);
    getchar();
}

///////////
```

**EDIT:** 
**basically** all I want to do is to work with templates.
I am hoping to pass all that char's (`file0` `file1` `file2` ... , `func0` `func1` `func2` ...) at compile-time into the function body. Concatenate them into the c-string `cstr_file` or `cstr_func` (again at compile-time). and at run-time just print constants when `failure == true`. 

 
my template accepts `2 * BUFFER_SIZE + 1` arguments so its over 500 of them at current configuration 

 
**Is my example doing that?** 
I am hoping that "specializing template with variable" is the right tool to do. All c-string with will be passed to this template with `SPLIT("...")` macro, are known at compile time.

 
**EDIT #2:** 
@olpa told me that my example is bug'y. I have re-upload it with newest 100% working version.

Comment: I edited your code into your question. In the future, please just paste it into the question and click the "Code sample" button to indent it. You might also want to read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create an MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You can use a `static_assert` and verify yourself whether it can evaluate at compile time or not

Comment: @TartanLlama thank you.

Comment: @Arunmu sory i am more like junior can you explain what it is? (compiler pramater ?)

Comment: @cukier9a7b5 First of all it's not clear to me which function you want to be evaluated at compile time. Is it `errchk` ? If yes, it cannot since you are using ostream which is a runtime construct.

Comment: sorry. 
main idea behind this is to evaluate at compile that massive template declaration.
**I would like to pass with that template chars to the function body at compile time.** these chars in the end would sum up to __FILE__ __func__ (i am working with mscv 2015, but it has its own definition of it) so it is known at compile time. **next thing** i am hoping that __forceinline specifier will force past the body of "errchk" function to the code. is it as fast as macros?

Comment: sory for 2nd comment. I have edited my question. it is now more clear.

Comment: I'd suggest to create a minimal *working* example, which compiles. Then we could compile the code and see what happens.

Comment: @olpa given example compiles just fine. This is working sample... **Edit:** ok there was a small error. Since my last comment i have change that example "a bit". New 100% working version is now available in example at main post.

Comment: Sorry, gcc under linux fails with several errors.

Comment: could past me an output (pastebin) ?? I would like to see it. I was sure this code could be compiled on windows and linux. after all i have been using only c++14 standard. (Have you change __forceinline to inline?? It is MSCV only).